# Finding the Fixed points of a Möbius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, fixed-points

Is there a method or algorithm that can be used to find the Fixed points of a Möbius transformation on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Quadratic formula?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For
$$
f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}
$$
the fixed points are the solutions of
$$
\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=z
$$
i.e.
$$
cz^2+(d-a)z-b=0
$$
a quadratic in $z$